# How to stop the execution of a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

In the following code I have the class The Thread, which inherits from threading to execute a task in a different thread, in this case the task is to show a.gif image in a QLabel, while another task is executed.

In this case, when emitting the signal that executes the Finish() function, the tabWidget() widget changes from index to 1

But when we return to index 0 we can see that the .gif is still running in the QLabel.

So I want to know how to stop the execution of that thread,
I tried

```
TheThread.kill()
TheThread.stop()
```

But it didn't work, this is the complete code with the .ui file and the image.gif

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QTabWidget,QPushButton,QLabel
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtGui
from PyQt5 import uic
import threading
import time

class TheThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,obj,fun):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.obj = obj
        self.fun = fun

    def run(self):
        self.fun()
class Main(QMainWindow):
    signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("Test.ui",self)

        self.Iniciar.clicked.connect(lambda:self.ShowImage())

        self.signal.connect(self.Finish)
        self._thread = TheThread(self,self.Fun1)

    def ShowImage(self):
        _movie = QtGui.QMovie("Loader.gif")
        self.Animacion.setMovie(_movie)
        self.Animacion.setScaledContents(True)
        _movie.start()

        self._thread.start()

    def Fun1(self):
        time.sleep(3)
        self.signal.emit(0)

    def Finish(self,signal):
        if signal == 0:
            time.sleep(1)

            self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
            # TheThread.kill()
            TheThread.stop()


app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
app.exec_()
```

File.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>30</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>691</width>
      <height>441</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
     <attribute name="title">
      <string>Tab 1</string>
     </attribute>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="Animacion">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>220</x>
        <y>40</y>
        <width>231</width>
        <height>171</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>TextLabel</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="Estatus">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>220</x>
        <y>270</y>
        <width>271</width>
        <height>16</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>TextLabel</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
     <attribute name="title">
      <string>Tab 2</string>
     </attribute>
    </widget>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="Iniciar">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>30</x>
      <y>460</y>
      <width>75</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>PushButton</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Image.gif[image]

Comment: Try killing the thread object, not its class: `self._thread.stop ()`. Note: a few other things should be improved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description does not match your code, nor with the correct logic.

- The gif that is part of the GUI must be executed in the main thread (GUI thread) and the heavy task in the secondary thread.
- Do not use time.sleep () in the main thread.
- That it finishes executing the heavy task does not imply that it is finished executing the gif, you have to stop it.

Considering the above, a simpler approach is to create a QObject that lives in another thread and execute the task there, that allows you to add the started and finished signals.

```py
import os
import time
from functools import partial
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic


current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


def callback():
    # emulate task
    time.sleep(3.0)


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    started = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(object)
    def task(self, fun):
        self.started.emit()
        fun()
        self.finished.emit()


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

        filename = os.path.join(current_dir, "Test.ui")
        uic.loadUi(filename, self)

        self.Animacion.setScaledContents(True)

        thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        thread.start()

        self._worker = Worker()
        self._worker.moveToThread(thread)
        self._worker.started.connect(self.show_image)
        self._worker.finished.connect(self.on_finished)

        wrapper = partial(self._worker.task, callback)
        self.Iniciar.clicked.connect(wrapper)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def show_image(self):
        _movie = QtGui.QMovie("Loader.gif")
        self.Animacion.setMovie(_movie)

        self.Animacion.movie().start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_finished(self):
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.Animacion.movie().stop()


def main():
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

@eyllanesc was right that you used the wrong thread and the better approach is to use a Qt GUI thread. However, I find it nice to demonstrate the multitude of ways of killing a thread in Python besides using the `stop()` or `kill()` methods (which btw, shouldn't they have been set to the `self._thread` variable you defined instead of the `TheThread` class?). These techniques are hackish in nature, but they work.

First, you can throw an exception, since exceptions always stop code from executing. This example uses the `ctypes` library:

```
import ctypes

def get_id(self): 

    # returns id of the respective thread 
    if hasattr(self, '_thread_id'): 
        return self._thread_id 
    for id, thread in threading._active.items(): 
        if thread is self: 
            return id

def raise_exception(self): 
    thread_id = self.get_id() 
    res = ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(thread_id, 
          ctypes.py_object(SystemExit)) 
    if res > 1: 
        ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(thread_id, 0) 
        print('Exception raise failure') 

self._thread.raise_exception();
```

You can also use a Boolean flag variable, that when set to true, executes a `break` statement, which ends the program. You could define the thread in a `run()` function and then the `join()` method is what essentially stops the thread:

```
def run(): 
   while True:
       global stop_threads 
       if stop_threads: 
          break

self._thread = threading.Thread(target = run)  
self_thread.start() 
stop_threads = True
self_thread.join()
```

You could also use a multiprocessing module, and instead of using a thread, you can use a process, which is very similar, the only difference being that threads run in the same memory space, while processes have separate memory. The `terminate()` method kills the process:

```
import multiprocessing 
import time 

def func(number): 
   for i in range(1, 10): 
       time.sleep(0.01) 
       print('Processing ' + str(number) + ': prints ' + str(number*i)) 

all_processes = [] 

for i in range(0, 3): 
   process = multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=(i,)) 
   process.start() 
   all_processes.append(process) 

# Kill all processes after 0.03s  
time.sleep(0.03) 
for process in all_processes: 
   process.terminate()
```

Finally, you can kill a thread by setting it to a daemon. By default, threads don't end when the program ends, so daemon threads are those threads which are killed when the main program exits:

```
def func(): 
   while True: 
      time.sleep(0.5) 
      print('Thread alive, but it will die on program termination') 

self._thread = threading.Thread(target=func) 
self._thread.daemon = True
self._thread.start() 
time.sleep(2)
sys.exit()
```